# Opacity mask an image in wpf weird bahvior

Tags: wpf, opacitymask

I try to make an opacity mask for an image in wpf via this xaml:

```
<Border x:Name="border1" Margin="20" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="50" >
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Wheat" x:Name="border2" CornerRadius="50"/>
        <Image Margin="0" Source="Images/SpiderMan.png" Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=border2}"/>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

this xaml works properly and is fine, but when i change **Elementname** to *border1* that does not work? why this happens?

Edited(another question):

in above xaml, image do not show until i set **Background** property of 
 **border2** but wht this happens? why without background property image do not show?

Comment: What exactly does "*work*" mean in this context?

Comment: @Clemens by running the app, image will be shown

Comment: @Clemens no, i defined a corner radius in border1 and when i add an image, added image have not a rounded corner . by defining opacitymask i wanna to make image corner rounded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Border1 can't be assigned to VisualBrush since it is a parent control. If such binding will be allowed.. you will faced with huge recursion and stackoverflow exception. Next XAML shold work

```
<Grid>
     <Border x:Name="border1" Margin="20" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="50" />
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Wheat" x:Name="border2" CornerRadius="50"/>
        <Image Margin="0" Source="Images/SpiderMan.png" Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=border1}"/>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: please describe more about recursion in a scenario when such data binding will be allowed.

Comment: VisualBrush requires rendered control.. from other side parent control dependent on content with such brush. So how do you think ... how many times Visual prooperty will be changed?

Comment: please see edited section in question:)

Comment: It is also expected.. border2 is not rendered in case if it without background..  VisualBrush was transparent..and it is converted to transparent opacity.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :)